# The use of the verb "think" in the progressive form in the sense of having some kind of opinion on something

Tags: stative-verbs

I am aware that the verb *think* can be used in the progressive form in some contexts, but it cannot be used in the progressive when someone is expressing one's opinion. But in this [video](https://youtu.be/lWXvQDP8mqo) a stand-up comedian who is seemingly an English native speaker uses it in the progressive form in the sense of having an opinion. It is it 4 minutes and 55 seconds. Here is the piece:

> But what **they were probably thinking** was Joe farted and then fell down on his chair.

Does that mean that the sentences such *I am thinking that he is a doctor* are actually acceptable and natur in day-to-day conversation?

Comment: Your first example is idiomatically unexceptional *for the specific context*. But your second example would probably be seen as a substandard "Indian English" usage, so you should avoid it.

Comment: Could you please explain why the first exemple is unexceptional, but my second sentence is off?

Comment: It's not easy to explain exactly why there's a difference. Since you're nns yourself, your biggest problem will almost certainly be that you'll tend to ***overuse*** the continuous form (which ***will*** be noticed by the natives in many contexts). But *in the exact cited example* there's no hint of "Indian English". One point that *may* make a difference is the presence of the qualifier ***probably*** (though I can't say exactly why). Without that, *what they **thought** was [that] Joe **had** farted* rolls off the tongue easily enough, but generally we wouldn't want the Perfect there.

Comment: ...maybe it's because the context is one where the stand-up comic is "painting a picture in words" of an amusing series of events - which ***extend over time***. So the idea being conveyed isn't so much about what the people ***thought*** (their "immediate" reaction / assessment, an action that doesn't really "extend over time"). It's more about ***continuing*** to believe something that's inherently incongruous / amusing. Note - although your exact example "works", no native speaker would ***ever*** use continuous *what they were probably **believing** was...* in such contexts, if that helps.

Comment: Could that be tha the use of "they were probably thinking" was some sort of background event against which the people concluded that Joe farted?

Comment: I think we need a wiser person than me to unravel this one. [@John Lawler](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2893/john-lawler) could probably explain why there's a difference, if he could be coaxed into engaging with it.

Comment: Thank you for your attemps! How do I ask him on this webside?) I guess there is no way I could do that

Comment: I doubt my "at-sign" in the previous comment will automatically "ping" John, since he hasn't yet posted on this page. One relevant factor here is our aversion to the continuous with "verbs of perception / judgement" is particularly strong in the ***Present*** tense *(I **am seeing** what you mean, She **is loving** him)*. I feel sure there must be *some* clearly-identifiable principle making the comic's usage okay, whereas my two examples in this comment would usually not be. I doubt it's *only* because it's Past Tense, but I simply don't know. Sorry! :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems (as usual) to be stated in the initial false presupposition.

> I am aware that the verb *think* can be used in the progressive form in some contexts,
>   but it cannot be used in the progressive when someone is expressing one's opinion.

I have no idea where this comes from, but it sounds like something a teacher might improvise on the spur of the moment when they couldn't answer a student's question. In some schools, this would then be passed on as `The Correct Answer` for the next ten generations. It's not a grammatical rule of English, however.

Pretty much **any** predicate can be used in the Progressive construction, **if** the speaker wants to indicate that whatever state or activity the predicate describes is not over yet at the time referred to.

In English, optional [constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/323532/15299) like Passive or Progressive don't change the basic meaning of the sentence, but they **do** guide the interpretation of the predicates. *Think* can express an action, or it can express a state of mind. [Mental process verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/321235/15299) are odd that way -- **all** mental process is imaginary, after all, so we can imagine it any way we please, as stative or active.

When the Progressive is used, however, it simply means that whatever *thinking* is being referred to is not instantaneous, as either state or action, but rather has an extension in time beyond the time the *thinking* is referred to. The thinker is not done thinking yet, in other words.

That's all, really, if you're only concerned with *think*. However, note that *think* is only one of many English mental process predicates, including emotion predicates and sense verbs, all of which have their own special unique grammars. Dictionaries are the wrong place to look for answers to grammatical questions; they deal with words, not constructions, but English grammar is all about constructions, not individual words.